# JTextArea.setText(null); does not free the memory

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jtextarea

I'm using Swing and I have a JFrame containing a few JPanels, and inside one of them there is a JTextArea.

The JTextArea content is set when an user clicks on a certain menu (*ActionListener.actionPerformed(populate())*).

The content is taken from a 30MB text file:

```
private void populate () {
        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("file30mb.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                strB.append(strLine).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            fr.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setText(strB.toString());
        jTextArea1.setCaretPosition(0);
}
```

This process takes a lot of memory usage, about 200MB.

There is another menu and when an user clicks on it the JTextArea is cleared (basically it calls a method that does *jTextArea1.setText(null)*). The event is handled the same way of before: *ActionListener.actionPerformed(free())*.

So when the JTextArea is empty I expect that the memory usage is lower than before... But unfortunately it's not true. If I go in the task manager I see the same memory usage of before (about 200MB), but the JTextArea is empty!

What am I missing?

**EDIT** I also tried this:

```
jTextArea1.setText(strB.toString());
jTextArea1.setText("");
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.gc();
System.out.println(jTextArea1.getDocument().getLength()); // prints "0"
```

But it still takes 200MB of memory.

**EDIT 2** If I remove the "GUI part" (I mean jTextArea1.setText() etc.) it still takes a lot of memory. It should take "0 memory" because I don't write anything in the JTextArea, but I just read a text file and then do nothing. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's possible that the GC does not act immediately. Are you keeping any other references to the large string anywhere?

Comment: please test JTextArea.getDocument (Model for JTextComponent), then to determine its getLength()

Comment: I'm not keeping any other references to the large string anywhere... They are only in that function. I'll test your suggests.

Comment: @mKorbel I tried and it returns "0" as expected.

Comment: @Pierpaolo Bagnasco basically all IDEs have got implemented or accesible JProfiler, profile single part, main + and to try JTextArea.read, there a few views where you can determine real memory usages including class or methods names including GC curves graph, btw in my case issue was somewhere so far as I expected :-),

Comment: @Pierpaolo Bagnasco notice no one of programing languages with output to the GUI is designated to display 5 - 10 not 30Mb file, aaaach I think that wrong concept and very lazy ....

Comment: Unfortunately I have to... I don't want to, but it's not my call :( Thanks for the suggest by the way, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few reasons:

- garbage collection runs periodically, it won't free memory immediately
- JVM process memory and heap memory usage are two distinct things. Enable verbose GC logging or connect to your application using `jconsole`/`jvisualvm` and check real heap usage. Run GC manually
- Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> still working, allowing you to restore previous (30 MB) contents? You get the idea...

If none of these are right, use memory profiler like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to find out what holds a reference to this huge object (you'll find `char[]` of 60 MB size).

Comment: Ctrl + Z doesn't work. So I tried to run GC manually, but it takes still 200MB of memory. (I edited my first post)

Comment: @PierpaoloBagnasco: so, what was the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the jconsole/jvisualvm suggest... I found out that I was simply wrong. I confused the memory committed with the actual heap memory used. I have used this library too: http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/ to know memory usage of each object of interest.